# The app's core functions are not usable on Windows 10 desktop and Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: cordova, ionic3, windows-10-mobile, windows-10-desktop

I have uploaded my ionic cordova app on Windows store app and I got the problem with certificate.

> App Policies: 10.1.2 Inaccurate Functionality
>
> App Policies: 10.3.1 App Is Not Testable
>
> Notes To Developer
>
> Unfortunately, we can’t test your app:  The app's core functions are
>   not usable.
>
> Blockquote
>   Steps to Reproduce:
>   1. Launch the app with Desktop.
>   2. The app shows a white blank page.
>   3. Notice that the app's core functions are not usable.
>
> Tested Devices: Windows 10 Desktop, Windows 10 Mobile
>
> App Policies: 10.1.1 Inaccurate Representation
>
> Notes To Developer
>
> Use screenshots that don’t show the app splash screen, debug
>   information, emulator chrome, the login screen or frame rate counters.
>   Please make this change and re-submit your app.

How could I solve it?

**Finding the problem source**

The problem of app not usable because I changed the packing name from

```
io.ionic.starter
```

to Windows app store information that provided by Microsoft developer account.

when I test the app locally becomes white screen because the package name and package family name are changed.

How do I fix this and connect between them to upload my app?

Comment: Didn't you test on `Windows 10 Desktop` and `Windows 10 Mobile`?

Comment: I want to run this App on Windows 10 tablet. How could I do this test?

Comment: Hope this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39743046/how-do-i-test-ionic-2-apps-on-a-windows-10-mobile-phone

Comment: @Sampath thanks, I read it carefully but actually this test on local mobile device, which I don't have. I have a self independent tablet that I cannot do these instructions. I have my simulator and my app shows white screen. Why do you think this?

Comment: If you have a simulator then you can debug it no?

Comment: @SampathI tested and it works fine but when I change the package name to be as windows app store publisher information, then it becomes white screen. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why don't you open an issue here? You need to provide a reproduced git repo of your project too: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/new